# Validar formulario en NbStepperComponent antes de ejecutar nbStepperNext

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando con [NbStepperComponent](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/stepper/api#nbsteppercomponent) de nebular en Angular 2, hasta ahora funciona bien, solo que al pasar al siguiente paso quiero realizar una previa validación desde en una función y recién ejecutar `nbStepperNext` pero no se como ejecutar el `nbStepperNext` desde una funcion, ya que su documentacion lo hace directamente desdel el HTML asi `<button nbButton nbStepperNext>next</button>`

Quisiera:"Ejecutar el `nbStepperNext` desde una `function` "

algo asi:

```
<button (click)="validacion()" type="button">Next</button>

validacion(){
//código de la validacion
       stepper.next(); // y pasar al siguiente paso
}
```

-Mi código base

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'nb-stepper-test',
      template: `
        <nb-stepper>
          <nb-step>
            <ng-template nbStepLabel>First step</ng-template>
            <div class="step-container">
              <h3>Información personal</h3>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre" style="width: 100%;" class="label">First Name</label>
                <input  type="text" nbInput id="nombre" fieldSize="small"  formControlName="nombre" fullWidth>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="paterno" class="label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" nbInput id="paterno" fieldSize="small" formControlName="paterno" fullWidth>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="correo" class="label">Correo</label>
            <input type="text" nbInput id="correo" fieldSize="small" formControlName="correo"  fullWidth>
        </div>
</div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled nbStepperNext>prev</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" nbStepperNext>next</button>
            </div>
          </nb-step>
          <nb-step>
            <ng-template nbStepLabel>Second step</ng-template>
            <div class="step-container">
              <h3>Step content #2</h3>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" nbStepperNext>next</button>
            </div>
          </nb-step>
          <nb-step label="Third step">
            <div class="step-container">
              <h3>Step content #3</h3>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" nbStepperNext>next</button>
            </div>
          </nb-step>
          <nb-step>
            <ng-template nbStepLabel>Fourth step</ng-template>
            <div class="step-container">
              <h3>Step content #4</h3>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled nbStepperNext>next</button>
            </div>
          </nb-step>
        </nb-stepper>
      `,
    })
    export class StepperTestComponent {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una referencia a `NbStepperComponent` usando `@ViewChild` y con eso ya puedes llamar a los métodos que expone la API de ese componente.

```
export class StepperTestComponent {

  @ViewChild(NbStepperComponent) stepper : NbStepperComponent

  next(){
      this.stepper.next()
   }

}
```

Comment: y como realizaría el import de `NbStepperComponent` para que no me marque en error el `@viewChild`?